# Override iframe width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to set the width of an iframe that has inline property using external CSS? The code is something like this.

```
<iframe src="video.html" width="625" height="430"></iframe>
```

For some reason setting the width to a fixed size works but I can't set it to 100%.

```
iframe{width:100% !important}
```

Comment: Setting `width: 100% !important;` should work, as shown here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/030L3k0u/)

Comment: There is probably another css rule interfering. It's always 100% of the parent container. Otherwise setting a 100% width should work.

Comment: Correct, so inspect the element in Browser inspector and check where it gets width from.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the culprit is Bootstrap's responsive embed class.

Answer (score -1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_width.asp:

> In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element. In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.